# How to get rid of Stayfocusd chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I installed Stayfocusd extension to boost my productivity and minimize time spent reading about dietary habits of Mongol soldiers in Genghis Khan's time, or the detailed differences between shallots and onions.

However I must have set some settings wrong as now I'm not able to visit any site. Even the browser settings page won't open and thus I can't remove the extension.

And worst of all I think I set the blocking period to be 1000 hours.

I can't reinstall chrome as I have my bookmarks and other settings in it. Is there a way to get rid of this evil plugin? (Like starting chrome in safe mode or something)

Comment: Haven't you heard of <Shift>+<Esc>?

Comment: @cst1992 Actually no, I hadn't. And that's quite useful. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Preferences → Extensions, and from the list click remove (bin icon on the right)

If that does not help, you can try the following:

- On Windows 7: close Chrome and go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` and remove the offending extension
- On Ubuntu 12.10 either:

  - go to `/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` and remove the extension
  - Launch Chrome from the terminal with the `-incognito` (or `--incognito`?) flag and remove the extension

Comment: Did I not mention - `Even the browser settings page won't open`.

Comment: I will asume you are on windows 7.. close Chrome and go to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ Extensions and remove the offending extension

Comment: Sorry. Ubuntu 12.10 but good idea let me look for that directory on my system.

Comment: Ok, much better. Launch chrome from the terminal with -incognito flag and remove the extension.

Comment: Many thanks, that works! Btw removing the extension directory under `/home/kshitiz/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` would also do the trick.

Comment: As of 2020 this Extension folder is all gibberish names. @user4113 answer worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I found an easier way to get rid of it on a Mac. Go to Chrome's `Tools > Task manager`, find `stayfocusd` and `End process`, then you can get to extensions page.

Comment: Clearly the best answer here ! Must be the accepted one since there is no problem with this plugin only wrong utilisation with the "Nuke Mode" I guess.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I'll answer it anyway in case someone else might find it helpful:

Go to System Preferences, and set the system time forward by a couple days or so. Simple as that.

Comment: This worked for me. Simple, easy!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the extension icon and then click "Remove from Chrome..." That doesn't involve opening a new Chrome tab, so it works even when the "Nuclear Option" is activated.

Answer (score 1):

This was an epic headache for Mac OS.  I don't know about other OS, but with Mac OS these Chrome Extensions are hashed with unique identifiers.  I had to `/Users/{your username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` and search for `stayfocusd`, delete a whole bunch of keys inside the `Preferences` file.  This led me to a key value `laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji`, I have no idea if this is unique on each system or if this is a Google Chrome Store internal hash value.  Anyway, I got Chrome free of this beast by FIRST closing Chrome, then deleting all references to `stayfocusd` AND `laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji` after searching the `/Users/{your username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Chrome os You go to more tools and click task-manger end the extention that is stayfoucesd and go to the extentions page and delete it

Comment: How is this different than @BrendenLyons answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following if you have blocked the extensions page too like me

- download another browser based on chromium like flashpeak slimjet
- Sign in to the same google account
- check out the extensions page. from Jigsaw button > Manage extensions
- Search stayfocusd
- Click remove extensions